# PowerShell - Add json to file content

Tags: json, powershell

I'm struggling to add some json code to an existing file with PowerShell.

Here's the json block that must be added on a specific location in the file.

```
$manualInterventionJson = @"
{
    "deploymentInput": {
        "parallelExecution": {
            "parallelExecutionType": 0
        },
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
        "condition": "succeeded()",
        "overrideInputs": {}
    },
    "rank": 2,
    "phaseType": 2,
    "name": "Agentless job",
    "refName": null,
    "workflowTasks": [
        {
            "environment": {},
            "taskId": "bcb64569-d51a-4af0-9c01-ea5d05b3b622",
            "version": "8.*",
            "name": "Manual Intervention",
            "refName": "",
            "enabled": true,
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "continueOnError": false,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "retryCountOnTaskFailure": 0,
            "definitionType": "task",
            "overrideInputs": {},
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "inputs": {
                "instructions": "test blablabla",
                "emailRecipients": "",
                "onTimeout": "reject"
            }
        }
    ]
}
"@
```

The json file has a complex structure. Here's a sample version:

```
{
    "source": 2,
    "variables": {},
    "environments": [{
        "name": "Deploy",
        "rank": 1,
        "deployPhases": [{            
            "rank": 1,
            "phaseType": 1,
            "name": "Agent job",
            "refName": null,
            "workflowTasks": [{
                "environment": {},
                "taskId": "##TASK_GROUP_ID##",
                "version": "1.*",
                "name": "##TASK_GROUP_NAME##",
                "condition": "succeededOrFailed()",
                "inputs": {}
            }]
        }],
        "postDeploymentGates": {
            "id": 0,
            "gatesOptions": null
        },
        "environmentTriggers": []
    }]
}
```

Note that currently there is only 1 deployPhase (rank 1) and rank 2 must be added, that is the json block up top.

This may also help in replicating the issue:
[image]

This is what the result would eventually look like:

[image]

I tested with `.Add()` to array and with `+=` or with `Add-Member`, I even tried creating a new Dictionary object `$obj = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"`, but that also doesn't work out because some values are of different types.

Edit: PS. I do not need to save the updated file. Just read the file `$jsonObj  = Get-Content "C:\temp\test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json`, update the content in a variable, no need to save to file.

I could use some guidance in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deployPhases` property contains an array, so creating a dictionary won't help here.

I would use the array subexpression operator `@(...)` in conjunction with `Sort-Object`:

```
# parse both the original document and the document to be inserted
$original = Get-Content "C:\temp\test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$newPhase = $manualInterventionJson |ConvertFrom-Json

# get a reference to the parent object
$targetEnvironment = $original.environments |Select -First 1

# construct a new deployPhases array by concatenating the new document and sorting by rank
$newDeployPhases = @(
  @($targetEnvironment.deployPhases;$newPhase) |Sort-Object rank
)

# overwrite existing deployPhases property with new list
$targetEnvironment.deployPhases = $newDeployPhases

# and finally convert the modified object hierarchy back to json
$modifiedJson = $original |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 15
```

`$modifiedJson` now contains the desired updates